# AEM 6.3 Using OSGi R6 Annotations and Sling Models

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling, htl

I am trying to create an OSGi Service using OSGi R6 annotations and then injecting it in the Sling Model class like this:

```
   package com.aem.sites.models;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.aem.sites.services.WeatherService;

@Model(adaptables=Resource.class)
public class Banner {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Banner.class);

    @Inject
    private WeatherService weatherService;

    private String message;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            logger.info("##############################################################calling the init method");
            message = weatherService.getName();
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            logger.info("##############################################################inside the get message method");
            return message;
        }

}
```

The OSGi configuration interface looks like this:

```
    package com.aem.sites.interfaces;

import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeType;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.ObjectClassDefinition;

@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Configuration", description = "Configuration file")
public @interface Configuration {

     @AttributeDefinition(
                name = "String Property",
                description = "Sample String property",
                type = AttributeType.STRING
            )
     public String getText() default "It's a test";
}
```

and the service class looks like this:

```
   package com.aem.sites.services.impl;


import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Deactivate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ConfigurationPolicy;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.Designate;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import com.aem.sites.interfaces.Configuration;
import com.aem.sites.services.WeatherService;

@Component(service=WeatherService.class,
immediate=true,
configurationPid = "com.aem.sites.services.impl.WeatherServiceImpl",
configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE
)
@Designate(ocd = Configuration.class)
public class WeatherServiceImpl implements WeatherService{

    final static Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeatherServiceImpl.class);

    private Configuration config;

    private String name;

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected final void activate(Configuration configuration) {
        logger.info("##############################################################calling activate method inside the weather service impl class");
        this.config = configuration;
        name = config.getText();
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        logger.info("##############################################################calling get name method inside the weather service impl class");
        return name;
    }
}
```

and finally the service interface:

```
package com.aem.sites.services;

public interface WeatherService {

    public String getName();

}
```

I am trying to use the Sling Model Pojo in the HTL class like this:

```
<sly data-sly-use.banner="com.aem.sites.models.Banner">

    <div class="inner">
        <h2>${banner.message}</h2

    </div>

</sly>
```

## But I am not able to see any texts. I have used the logger.info but can't see it in the log files either. I am sure I am doing something very wrong here but unable to locate since I have just started playing with OSGi R6 annotations and Sling Models. Any help is appreciated.

Adding Maven dependencies:

Parent pom.xml

```
<!-- <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.3</version>
                </plugin>  -->             
                <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>3.3.0</version>
                      <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>

<dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.0</version>
               <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.annotation</artifactId>
              <version>6.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Core pom.xml

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.annotation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.aem.site.aem-site</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Sling-Model-Packages>
                          com.aem.sites.models
                        </Sling-Model-Packages>
                         <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: In your model: Can you please replace `@Inject` with `@OSGiService`? In the official documentation the `@Inject` was used for a model that was adapted from `SlingHttpServletRequest`. You are adapting from `Resource`. This might make a difference, although I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

In the service impl you have put `service=WeatherServiceImpl.class` which is incorrect, it should be the service interface name.

so, in WeatherServiceImpl change

```
 @Component(service=WeatherServiceImpl.class,
```

to

```
 @Component(service=WeatherService.class,
```

..

**EDIT**:  also `configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` means that there should be at least one config in order for the DS component to be active. (config from code wont work)

so you can go to system /system/console/configMgr/com.aem.sites.services.impl.WeatherServiceImpl and put a value and save. or you can set configurationPolicy to optional and your code will work without config.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Already did that but nothing changed.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the changes made in both the pom files. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: this is strange. I tried on 6.3 and was able to get the message output in sightly. I made the following changes though - 1. change package names to match my sandbox setup. 2. replaced log4j logger with slf4j logger

Comment: I have updated my code with minor edits. Not that it has made any difference though. Can you please check if everything still works fine ? I have also implemented slf4j

Comment: I am pretty much positive there is nothing wrong with the code at this point. also I am assuming you already checked that the bundle is active in system console, the service component is active etc. maybe you can put all your code on github and share link.

Comment: Here is the bitbucket URL https://bitbucket.org/ankit909/aem-site. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: you will have to make the repo public

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156211/discussion-between-user972418-and-awd).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the Sling Models available you have to properly configure `<Sling-Model-Packages>` section of the `maven-bundle-plugin`, see https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#basic-usage

You can check the models are properly exposed by using the Sling Models Web Console: http://localhost:4502/system/console/status-slingmodels

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you think the <sling-model-packages> section is not properly configured In the same package i.e. <com.aem.sites.models> I have other sling model classes and they seem to be working fine. But this is one class that is not working as expected. I also tried using WCMUsePojo but even that didn't work. So, I don't know if the pom.xml have some issues or is it something else.

Comment: The latest update of the `pom.xml` fragment looks ok. I verified and it's working ok on AEM 6.3. I suspect you're not including the HTL script correctly, try to define a minimal HTL script with the above snippet at `/apps/test/banner/banner.html` and a node at `/content/test` with `sling:resourceType=test/banner` and see it gets rendered correctly at `/content/test.html`

Comment: Are you able to build the project correctly ? I am asking this is because I observed some issues with maven build. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659511/aem-6-3-maven-build-is-successful-but-still-doesnt-install-all-the-content

Comment: I copy pasted your classes and script into a working project