# AEM 6.3 - Maven build is successful but still doesn't install all the content

Tags: maven, aem

I am having this weird issue where I have created a fresh new AEM project using lazybones and then when I ran the maven build for the first time the project structure got created in the CRXde. Then I created a component in the CRXde and exported it using vlt too. Made some changes to the component HTL file and ran the maven build. ***EDIT** The changes are reflected in the component script but if I delete the component from the CRXde and run the build again, the component isn't installed even though the build has been successful. The same hold true for any file or folder, be it under apps/. etc/clientlibs/ or under /conf. When I check the zip file that is created as a result of the build I can see the zip files containing all the files and folder under project.

Below are the image explaining the issue:

Zip file containing the components

[image]

After the build the folders inside component are still empty

[image]

Even when I installed the zip package manually, for some reason I still can't the components, clientlibs and other files.

When I check the build logs, I didn't find any error apart from these warnings:

[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.3:bundle (default-bundle) @ example-project.core ---
[WARNING] Bundle com.myco:example-project.core:bundle:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT : Unused Private-Package instructions, no such package(s) on the class path: [!*]
[WARNING] Bundle com.myco:example-project.core:bundle:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT : The JAR is empty: The instructions for the JAR named com.myco.example-project did not cause any content to be included, this is likely wrong

I have no idea why this is happening since I haven't even made any changes to the pom.xml yet.

Also, if that matters, I am using maven 3.5.0

build parameters

[image]

Thanks in adance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/my-aem-project"/>

    <filter root="/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler"/>


    <filter root="/conf/my-aem-project" mode="merge"/>


    <filter root="/etc/clientlibs/my-aem-project"/>


    <filter root="/etc/designs/my-aem-project">
        <include pattern="/etc/designs/my-aem-project/jcr:content"/>

        <include pattern="/etc/designs/my-aem-project/jcr:content/clientlibs"/>
        <include pattern="/etc/designs/my-aem-project/jcr:content/clientlibs/.*"/>

    </filter>

</workspaceFilter>
```

---

This morning I checked out the project from git in my second laptop and did a maven build. The components, clientlibs etc nothing shows up in the CRXde and the build is successful.

Comment: Have you checked your content package filter rules?

Comment: Added the filter.xml file to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens when the project is configured to use filevault. It is recommended to use AEM eclipse plugin to keep CRX and eclipse codebase in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Check your filter.xml. Have you made the filter root entries in filter.xml?

Comment: I couldn't find any vault.xml file in the project.

Comment: I mean filter.xml available under Meta-INF > vault